# ¿Cómo soluciono el error al importar skimage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

He querido correr un programa, aclaro que lo descargue para ver el funcionamiento y los resultados de una red neuronal en Python, pero me marca el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   from skimage import color, io
> ImportError: No module named 'skimage'
> ```

Ya instalé la librería con:

```
pip install -U scikit-image
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

> **Nota:** Estoy trabajando con Python 3.5.2 y tensorflow en Windows.

Comment: ¿Te da algún error al instalar con `py -3.5 -m pip install scikit-image` o alguna de sus dependencias o se completa con éxito?¿En que directorio la instala PIP? ¿Está este directorio en tu PYTHONPATH?

Comment: me manda error en el : PATH

Comment: Airan usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/109022/edit) que hay debajo de la pregunta y agrega en ella la información que quieras, es el lugar oportuno y más cómodo que los comentarios. `py-3.5 -m pip freeze` te deberia mostrar la lista de módulos instalados, si `py -3.5 -m pip install scikit-image` instala sin problemas debería aparecer en la lista. ¿Usas algún entorno virtual?¿tienes otras versiones de Python instaladas?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a importar primero la librería como:

```
import skimage
```

y después:

```
from skimage import color
```

A mí me funcionó de esa forma. Saludos.

Comment: Hola primero que nada muchas gracias por tu aportación ,ya intente de esa manera y me sigue marcando el mismo error .Pero seguiré intentando .